# JavaScript slider dynamically changed + HTML/CSS , not changing pictures

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site where in the main menu there is a image , which i want to be changed every 5 seconds . 
The image is refered in the CSS class , and i need this image to be changed every 5 seconds with another image. For this i have writen a JavaScript code and added additional url's in the css . 
But there is something wrong with the Javascript code which i can not catch . 
First i get a message in the console that my variable MaxSlider is not defined. 
And second i think in my function 'changeMainSlider' i am not pointing correctly .

```
<main class="container">
   <div class="main-image">
      <div class="text">
         <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
         <div class="title2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</main>

.main-image {
    height:  340px;
    background: url(img/slide.jpg), url(img/gallery-1.jpg), url(img/gallery-2.jpg) center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}




var mainSlider = new MaxSlider('.main-slider');
var mainSliderInterval;
changeMainSlider();
var main_slider_el = document.getElementsByClassName('.main-slider');
main_slider_el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
    clearInterval(mainSliderInterval);
});
main_slider_el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
    changeMainSlider();
});

function changeMainSlider() {
    mainSliderInterval = setInterval(function () {
        mainSlider.nextItem();
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName and similar methods return a collection not a single element, also you pass it just the class name not a css selector

Comment: Looks like you need to import MaxSlider from another library?

Comment: I can remove the MaxSlider or just make it  var mainSlider = document.getElementByClassName('.main-slider');  . I am just not sure how to access the css property of the class name and make it slide through the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I made some configuration. The first time i had some mistakes and some missed code . 
After i changed it to :

```
<div class="max-slider" id="main-slider">
                <div class="list-items">>
                    <div class="item">
                            <div class="main-image">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
                                        <div class="title2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                            <div class="main-image2">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
                                        <div class="title2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                            <div class="main-image3">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
                                        <div class="title2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<script> 
var mainSlider = new MaxSlider('main-slider');

var mainSliderInterval;
changeMainSlider();

function changeMainSlider() {
    mainSliderInterval = setInterval(function () {
        mainSlider.nextItem();
    }, 5000);
}

     var main_slider_el = document.getElementById('main-slider');
      main_slider_el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
          clearInterval(mainSliderInterval);
        });
        main_slider_el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
            changeMainSlider();
        });
function MaxSlider(id) {
    this.id = id;   // main-slider
    var first_item = document.querySelector('#' + this.id + ' .item:first-child');
    first_item.classList.add('current');

    this.nextItem = function () {
        var currentEl = document.querySelector('#' + this.id + ' .current');
        currentEl.classList.remove('current');
        if (currentEl.nextElementSibling) {
            currentEl.nextElementSibling.classList.add('current');
        }
        else {
            first_item.classList.add('current');
        }
    };

}
</script>
```

And to every "main-image" class i added a different background-image in the CSS and for the slider :

```
.max-slider .item {
    display: none;
}
.max-slider .item.current {
    display: block;
}
```

Or just add inline style , `background-image:(url)` to every `<div class="main-image`